# Is there is trajectory planner for quadrotor / holonomic robot in ROS?

Tags: ros, navigation, moveit, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I wan to control a quadrotor with move_base package, this quadrotor is stable controlled by it's on-board processer, so I just need to move it.

But the problem is this quadrotor can not accept velocity_yaw command, or if I send rotation command it will become very unstable.

So, I want to know is there a path planner for only translation without rotation?

Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255580/is-there-is-trajectory-planner-for-quadrotor-/-holonomic-robot-in-ros?/) by [great82149](https://answers.ros.org/users/29482/great82149/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use the teb_local_planner package and set the parameters max_vel_theta: 0 and min_vel_theta: 0.
In that case, the planner generates only translations. You need to set the yaw_goal_tolerance: 6.28 as well in order to prevent that the planner desperately tries to rotate towards the final orientation.

Cheers Jochen

---

Originally posted by [Dr.Jekyll](https://answers.ros.org/users/32683/dr.jekyll/) with karma: 16 on 2017-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0